# Center Popover in Viewport

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

How should I center a React Material-UI Popover in the viewport?

My app is built on the Next.js framework, which is built on React.  (I have included the full dependencies from my package.json below.)

I have an element that opens a Popover when it is clicked:

```
        <Popover
            id="video-popover"
            open={Boolean(video)}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'center',
                horizontal: 'center'
            }}
            transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'center',
                horizontal: 'center'
            }}
        >
            <video controls autoPlay src={`/static/${video}`}>
                Your browser does not support the
                    <code>video</code> element.
                </video>
        </Popover>
```

I would like to get the video to be centered in the view.

Normally I would set the anchorEl property of the Popover element and the Popover would be centered over that anchor element.  But, what element should I use to center in the viewport?

---

In case it's not obvious, the onClick handler just sets state.video to the filename of the video to be played.  The onClose handler sets state.video to null.  If you need me to upload more of the JSX code, let me know, but I'm pretty sure it's not relevant to the centering of the Popover on the viewport.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.6.2",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-icons": "^3.2.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a full screen popover layer behind it, like modal's usually have. Make a div that's fixed position with a width of 100vw and a height of 100vh. Then use that as your anchor element. You'll have to hide and show it as needed.

Comment: that sounds like the right solution.  I was in the process of learning `React.createRef()` and hoisting the video player to the top Component.  (Don't laugh.)

Your solution sounds much cleaner and more modular.

I haven't used fixed pos divs to show a Popover before.  Do you have a link or some sample code you can recommend?

Comment: webdevdani that previous comment was to you, but I had trouble getting it to work.  Hope this one sticks...

Comment: For some reason, that Popover wouldn't center on the 100vh div. Not sure why not.  In the end, I just used a Modal.

Answer (score 12):

There is an other way to do it:

Popove has already a `Div` element with `fixed` position which contains the popover content, so we can just give it the style, and set the `anchorReference` to `none`.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  makeStyles,
  Popover,
} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles (theme => ({
  popoverRoot: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
}));

const CenteredPopOver = ({open}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Popover
      open
      anchorReference={"none"}
      classes={{
        root: classes.popoverRoot,
       }}
    >
      // what ever should be in the popover
      <div>I am in the center</div>
    </Popover>
  )
}
```

And for MUI v5 @JJL has a good solution:

```
<Popover
  open
  anchorReference={"none"}
  sx={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  }} >
   // what ever should be in the popover
   <div>I am in the center</div>
</Popover>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for giving the reasoning behind the answer as well as the solution itself.  Here it is with the sx prop, for those using MUI v5: 
<Popover
        open
        anchorReference={"none"}
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >